# Search for file names containing space

Tags: batch-file, windows-command-prompt, command

I have a batch file that helps me in install multiple pieces of software from a shared folder.

It's working well with software whose names don't contain spaces, but I need it to work with software does.

this code is working fine because thereis no space in the software name (firefox.exe):

**`for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b \\sharedfolder\*firefox*.exe') do %%a`**

if i trying the same code with a software that has space in the name, it's not working,

for example **`for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b \\sharedfolder\mozzila *firefox* 36.0.4.exe') do %%a`**

please look at the software name and you will understand what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for /f %a in ('/s /b \\sharedfolder\*firefox*.exe') do "%a"
```

You seem to have doubled up your <kbd>%</kbd>'s and would need to quote the variable for it work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
rem    ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "\\sharedfolder\mozzila *firefox* 36.0.4.exe"') do (
    rem  ↓   ↓  note double quotes  ↑                                           ↑    
    ECHO "%%a"
)
```

**Explanation**:

- [`"delims="` option](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) suppresses tokenization of `dir /B` output;
- [Double Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html): *if a single parameter contains spaces, you can still **pass it as one item** by surrounding in "quotes" - this works well for long filenames*;
- `ECHO "%%a"`: an operational command is merely displayed for debugging purposes; remove the word `ECHO` no sooner than debugged!